# How to extract directory names from a path in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a path like this

```
/home/user/doc/loc
```

I want to extract home, user, doc, loc separately. I tried `split (////)` and also `split("/")`
but none of them worked. Please give me sample script:

```
while (<EXPORT>) {
if (/^di/) { 
    ($key, $curdir) = split(/\t/); 
    printf "the current dir is %s\n", $curdir;
    printf("---------------------------------\n");
    ($home_dir, $user_dir, $doc_dir, $loc_dir) = split("/");    
  }
 }
```

But it didn't work; hence please help me.

Comment: [`File::Spec`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Spec.html) and `splitdirs`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given `$curdir` containing a path, you'd probably use:

```
my(@names) = split m%/%, $curdir;
```

on a Unix-ish system. Or you would use [`File::Spec`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Spec.html) and `splitdir`. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Spec;

my $curdir = "/home/user/doc/loc";
my(@names) = split m%/%, $curdir;

foreach my $part (@names)
{
    print "$part\n";
}

print "File::Spec->splitdir()\n";
my(@dirs) = File::Spec->splitdir($curdir);

foreach my $part (@dirs)
{
    print "$part\n";
}
```

Ouput (includes a leading blank line):

> `home`
>   `user`
>   `doc`
>   `loc`
>   `File::Spec->splitdir()`
>    
>   `home`
>   `user`
>   `doc`
>   `loc`

Answer (score 0):

`split`'s first result will be the string preceding the first instance of the regular expression passed to it.  Since you have a leading "/" here you would get an empty string in `$home_dir`, 'user' in `$user_dir` and so on.  Add `undef` to the list assignment's first position or alternatively trim a leading slash first.

Also I'm not sure if you can call split without passing it `$curdir` here.  Try:

```
(undef, $home_dir, $user_dir, $doc_dir, $loc_dir) = split("/", $curdir);
```

Comment: Instead of a "throwaway value", you can use `undef` as an lvalue exactly for that. It should also be noted that the first argument to `split` is *not* a string, but a regex!